# Dynamic warmups in Yoga class

Tags: stretching, yoga, hiit, warm-up, pilates

I'm currently trying to become a Yoga instructor and I have been thinking about my sequence of movements. I have never seen dynamic warmups like `Jumping Jack`, `High Knee`, `Inchworms`, `Burpees` etc in a Yoga class. My first question is,

- Why is that the case?

I'm personally thinking of doing that because the audience I'm trying to instruct mostly has a very sedentary life (office workers), most likely they wouldn't have walked like 1km (to a yoga studio for example) before starting the Yoga class. Although we do have "warmups" in the beginning of the class, but (also from my own experience) I think given the rigid and stiff state the body is in, even a half split or forward fold might create some (minor) injury or at least not so comfortable, or may not be enough for the more intense poses to come, so in these cases, wouldn't doing some dynamic movement to get the blood flow, muscle warmed up and heart rate going be quite beneficial?

I reached out to one of my teacher training teachers, and the reply I got was mainly two points:

> 1. The movement needs to be tied to the breath
> 2. People signed up for Yoga, not a HIIT workout or Pilates.

My thoughts are:

1. I indeed agree that a dynamic movement would be hard to keep mindful breathing at least the breath in Yoga, but this will only be 5 or 10 mins at most, so I don't really think this is an issue.
2. In the end, I think the reason people come to class (or any other class) is to be healthy, strong or/and mindful, so if a dynamic warmup (although different type normally done in yoga) would be more beneficial (in the setting of where participants did not have much movement prior to class), I think it would be okay.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.